# Securely shuffling an array with 75 numbers in Go

Tags: beginner, random, go, shuffle

I have a SHA512 hex string consisting of my random input and that of the user.

Since `rand.Seed` only accepts a `int64` I can never generate enough possibilities to shuffle an array with numbers 1-75: 75! = 2.480914e+109.

So my plan was to loop over the hex string 11 times, each time converting 10 hex characters to decimal and keep on shuffling the numbers.

```
func Shuffle(t []int, hex string) {
    for j := 0; j < 11; j++ {
        shuffleSeed, _ := strconv.ParseInt(hex[j*10:(j+1)*10], 16, 64)
        rand.Seed(shuffleSeed)
        for i := 1; i < len(t); i++ {
            r := rand.Intn(i + 1)
            if i != r {
                t[r], t[i] = t[i], t[r]
            }
        }
    }
}

items := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45,
    46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
    61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75}

hex := "099b5721eaa9b5bcd87a07366aa175a1fb5b6fa6e5671b93ef443df927474198ec2ae959928f95c46f9fe9621575aa4e1e6f70780b059044da17737fcc99a322"
Shuffle(items, hex)
```

What do you think about this? I'm not a cryptography expert, not a math expert and certainly not a Go expert (I started yesterday).

Taken from another post I shuffled an array with [1,2,3] and here are the occurrences of each after 1 million times:

> ```
> 167136
> 166403
> 166877
> 166520
> 166925
> 166145
> ```

Comment: Do you realize that that is a completely deterministic "shuffle"? Run the program any number of times, and the resulting order will be exactly the same. Is that your intention?

Comment: I removed the benchmark part from the post.

Anyways, it is my goal to reproduce results given the same input. But the `hex` part in my sample code will be different every time. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Then where does the `hex` string come from? You've asked about the randomness properties of the shuffle, but haven't told us much about the source of that randomness, except that it derives from the SHA512 hash of some other data, and it's hard-coded in your shuffling program.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Since I have no control of it. I generate a random string and the user inputs a string. I generate a SHA512 hash of those two strings together and take the hex value from it. It's only hardcoded there for demonstration purposes of my code. Since I don't know what the user inputs and the user doesn't know what I input we have pseudorandom seed for the shuffling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Initialization

A simple loop would be easier to maintain than hard-coding an array of 75 values.

```
items := make([]int, 75, 75)
for i := range items {
    items[i] = i + 1
}
```

### Seeding

The PRNG should be [seeded just once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12321133/1157100).

You are correct that an `Int64` seed is "only" capable of producing 2<sup>64</sup> ≈ 10<sup>19</sup> distinct sequences, which is well under 75! ≈ 10<sup>109</sup>.

However, you should also consider the magnitude of the numbers involved.  The [age of the Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_the_universe) is well under 10<sup>18</sup> seconds.  There is therefore no way you could remotely come close to producing a small fraction of the 75! possible permutations, just due to lack of time.  A 64-bit seed is more than enough to generate as many unreproducible sequences as you could ever want.

So, calling `rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())` just once in `func init()` will be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer! Due to the nature of my "game" I will need to reproduce the results and prove it to the user. So I think I'll keep going with the first 10 hex characters converted to `int64` as the seed. Every time the `Shuffle` function is called the hex will be different. So I'll guess that's fine.